# RcppArmadillo fastLm prediction intervals

Tags: r, rcpp

I am working with fastLm from the RcppArmadillo library. When I call the predict function I am able to get my prediction, but no prediction interval is created around that prediction. Is this not possible with the fastLm model?

```
library(RcppArmadillo)
df1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
df2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
lm1 <- fastLm(df1, df2)
pm1 <- predict(lm1, 5, interval='pint', level = 0.9)
pm1
[1] 5
```

Comment: Contributions welcome :)  You know where the repo is ...

Comment: Haha, alright. Maybe when I have free time.